# How can my rubber plant revive?

Tags: plant-health

[image]My Rubber plant shed it's leaves completely, just the last top leaf is left now. The leaves fall turning black from the tips. It was bought from a local nursery in Dec and repotted during spring, it was doing fine till last of may. How can I save it? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black leaf tips are a sign of too much water. These plants like very little watering, say every 2 weeks. Let the soil dry out in between waterings. Also they prefer a spot with indirect sun light (no direct sun light!).

Comment: Will it survive if I will water it once a week or its gone?

Comment: If you'll keep overwatering it, it will probably die. Don't know how long it will survive, why you want to keep giving it more water than it needs?

Comment: I mean to say that probably I watered it too frequently but I use to use finger check method to water my plants, when at least 2 inches of the top soil is dry and the soil is well drained. When should I water it next now?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. My advice is to keep it from watering for at least 2 weeks for now. Then, if soil feels dry you can give it again and try to keep the 2 weeks cycle. Also good drainage is important, the pot should have holes, and the soil should contain preferably something like grit or perlite.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will definitely follow it and update the condition of my rubber plant soon. There is garden soil and manure as potting mix in 50:50, it's drainage is very good and pot has 4 pencil thick holes.